# Перевести БД с MySQL на MySQLi - реализация

Tags: mysql

доброго всем дня!
С прошедшим прадзником ПОБЕДЫ!
Вопрос такой: 
Можно ли конвертировать\перевести БД с MySQL на MySQLi, в частности для joomla, ну и так, на будущее?
*(просто уже некоторые плагины не встают, да и говорят, что всё... MySQL умирает... поддержка+разработка уже в этом направлении вестись не будет)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://habrahabr.ru/post/141127/ - здесь описание функций работы с Mysqli, разница с Mysql заключается в обращении из PHP-скриптов. Конвертация базы не требуется.Если переносите joomla, то придется переписывать все функции обращения к базе, скорее всего так. Либо переписывать код плагинов.